# Passing a type instead of a value when using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to manually build a ts file, but can't seem to figure out how to do it the correct way. I have a property which will be a list of enum class names (types). For each of these I will call a method with creates a ts file. Method creating files (start):

```
public static bool CreateJsonFiles<T>(object item, string filePath = null)
{
    try
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<T>();
        if (filePath == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Beforehand I used the T generic parameter, by calling the function like

```
EnumsBuilder.CreateJsonFiles<LocatieType>($"{Server.MapPath("/")}");
```

The problem is that I wish to call the method for multiple value now (in an iteration). I've tried two things that both do not work:

1. Change generic method to remove  parameter, and use typeof(item):

   ```
   var type = item.GetType();
   var values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<type >();
   ```

   This gives an error on the Cast function.
2. Try to obtain the type of the items in the list in the iteration and try to pass this along:

   ```
   public static List<Type> EnumList { get; set; }

    public static void BuildEnums(string serverPath)
    {
       foreach (var item in EnumList)
       {
           var type = item.GetType();         
           CreateJsonFiles<type>(type, serverPath);
       } 
    }
   ```

   This also gives an error, because this is not allowed either.

Could anyone explain me the correct way to do this?

Comment: @Jon I doubt you need to cast here at all and thus you don't need reflection to call a generic method...

Comment: @PatrickHofman: It's a bit of an XY question, yes. I was closing as a duplicate in terms of the question that was actually asked, rather than working out whether the OP really should be taking that route at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt why you would need the `Cast` at all. The cast will not change the actual type of the data (unless you use conversion operators, which I doubt here). It will only change the type of the variable.

I guess you can use just this:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(type);
```

And for your `CreateJsonFiles` method, since you don't actually need the generic type parameter, you can make it non-generic instead.

Comment: This seems to shove the problem to later in the code. At some point I want to enumerate through the collection and the .Cast creates an enumerable allowing this. If I do not use cast I receive an Array, which I seem to only be able to cast back via OfType<T>(), another generic method

Comment: But you don't ever use the generic type parameter `T`, so why make it generic at all?

Comment: @Kai If the whole point of the cast is, that you need the IEnumerable<T> interface for some reason, just use `Cast<object>()`... you don't use `T` anyway.

Comment: @Patrick: The generic parameter was needed for the cast (or otherwise for OfType<T>) This worked well for 1 item, but now that I have a list I cannot find the correct data to pass as T anymore

Comment: But you didn't give any reason why you need `OfType` or `Cast` and why you can't just replace that with the non-generic type variant.

Comment: @both: I see the problem now. The problem was indeed that I was using T in the wrong way, while I did not even need it here. Thanks both for your reactions